# Significance of a SADGURU, in the confusing age of Kali

Tags: culture, guru, yogi, gurukul, ignorance

In times today people are living into full of temporary information overriden constantly, without much time devoted to learning about self.

Is there any way one can devote himself to a SADGURU without deviation caused by the Maya of selfishness ~to how personalities like SWAMI VIVEKANANDA did, while also completing worldly duties.

There's only selfishness, marketing and business attitudes seen everywhere.

Even in school children there's some sort of digital habits ingrained which seems to destroy their natural way of thinking, which makes them think spirituality is just for old/time pass/passive and helpless peoples of society.

Cause: They aren't given a spiritual shelter unlike past, which can let them Know the fact that this material world is just a reflection, so has no meaning without the spiritual side of life- just like a bulb has no meaning without electricity.

Comment: The reason spirituality is refuted in this Kali yuga is due to the absence of proof. For example there are gurus who claim to live without food or water who refuse to let them be examined by scholars. The natural way of thinking is not destroyed rather improved. We must remain critical thinkers. More hindus are subscribing the fact that the stories in the scriptures are mythology rather than actual history.

Comment: I understand that it's very difficult to become a disciple, and for a SADGURU to invest efforts in. Moreover, faith is degrading day by day.... people believe complan/boost,etc products to be more nutritious than milk  which has complete nutrition.

Comment: It is for people a lot easier to become a disciple if there is hard proof yet the gurus never met their burden of proof.

Comment: @Saurabh The problem starts when you listen to some critics or see this so called society way of life who does nothing but demotivates others. When you do something just be focused on that, what others think doesn't matter. There is nothing in this world if one wants to achieve and finds no difficulties in that. There will always be difficulty, one should be ready to face it.

Comment: actually, it's more concerning regarding learning system. Earlier, gurukul kind of system allowed learning sanskaras along with necessary life skills, education.

Comment: Saurabh - don't be misled by folks like @Wikash_. They make tall claims about being critical/skeptical, but when asked to do the same, they back off due to cowardice. All our rishis and acharyas have been, and will always be, willing to subject their claims to critical examination and hard proof. Suppose they make a claim, "if you do X penance for 12 years, you will achieve Y siddhi", most of these so called 'skeptics' don't have the courage to undertake such sadhana for even 12 days, so they blame the acharyas like the fox blaming sour-grapes

Comment: @Saurabh In India, there are many Gurukulam existing where we can receive ancient time education. There is a good one in Maharastra.

Comment: @ram "All our rishis and acharyas have been, and will always be, willing to subject their claims to critical examination and hard proof. " Well that is good yet proof was never given. So explain that. Also, I do not back out in courage I just note the absence of proof while you back out and refuse to give the proof yourself.

Comment: Thats the point, every person is Spiritual and Dharmic in Satyuga and Gurukula, but one who will stick to Dharma and spirituality even in Kaliyuga like a lotus floating in dirt, indeed will stand out and soon be liberated. Hence simple bhakti done in Kaliyuga bear deep fruits rather than penance and cramming spiritual books without mind-purification first. Accepting God, Brahmloka, Pitrloka, presence of soul etc., without any proof is mere parrot cramming and an insult to human's intellect/reasoning, hence modern equipments have been developed to enhance rational thinking among today's masses.

Comment: @Wikash_, proof has been given. all you need to do is verify it. If i say, "mango tastes sweet", you ask "what is the proof?", i say "simple. taste it and you'll verify it yourself". you say "nah, i won't taste it, still prove it". i say "good luck"

Comment: @ram proof is not given for there is no mango at all. It would be very nice to have such tangible evidence in Hinduism yet that has never occurred. Rishis and acharyas have had multiple instances to show proof yet they never agreed to the investigation of scientists.

Comment: @Wikash_, at this point, you're just lying.

Comment: @ram why do you think that?